# Single Sign On using SAML 2.0 authentication types

Tags: windows, active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs

I have an issue with a client about the authentication methods from the Identity Provider, (ADFS).

However, the client has two type of users, Internal users (within their network) and External ones, they need the ADFS to force the windows authentication for the internal users and the Form-based authentication for the External users,

The problem here is that we were sending one authentication method with the request and ADFS was using this method for all users,

Then we modified the code to be able to send both authentication methods in the request, so ADFS can choose which authentication method to be used, but ADFS didn't work as expected and it was ignoring the windows authentication and only uses the Form-based authentication,

These authentication methods we sent in the request to the ADFS,

urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
        urn:federation:authentication:windows

As you can see we sent the two types of authentication in the request but it didn't help!!

If you tell me how the request should be so ADFS can use the both authentication types I would appreciate it!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the operating system for adfs?

2012 r2 adfs introduced authentication policies where internal and external uses can be offered different authentication mechanisms. If you configure the global authentication policy in adfs correctly without specifying a uri for the authentication type in authnrequest you'd get what you want out of the box by default.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, It's 2012 r2 adfs, what I did is sending the two authentication methods in separated tags, but that didn't solve the issue, I'll try sending nothing and see how the ADFS behaves.

Comment: Note you need to ensure ad fs guys deployed web application proxy servers. This is used to determine if request is internal or external. Request through wap are deemed external and so forms based auth (password) by default provided your admin hasn't changed the default behaviour

Comment: I appreciate your help, your answer helped us, thank you!